# Choose a 'case' (of a switch) only after the database has been read

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

I've been discovering Node through Express (instead of Meteor I used to use). And I am cornered by a kind of asynchronous-thing..

Below a function (to read a mongo collection)

```
function isAuthorized(x) {

        // Connect to database when Bq. receives a message
        mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO, function (err, db) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server')
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established')
                let Users = db.collection('users')
                Users.find( {_id: From} ).toArray(function (err, result) {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) }
                    else if (result.length) {
                        console.log("found");
                        // switch (true) {
                        //     case x == null && result.authorization == null : return true
                        //     break ;
                        //     case x == false && result.authorization == false : return true
                        //     break ;
                        //     case x == true && result.authorization == true : return true
                        //     break ;
                        //     default: return false
                        //} // end of switch()
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("does not exist");
                        if (x == 'unknown user') { console.log("return true"); return true }
                    }
                    db.close()
                })
            }
        })
    } // end of isAuthorized()
```

This function is called into a switch().

```
switch (true) {

        case isAuthorized('unknown user') : something
        case XYZ
        case ABC
        Default: console.log("default") 
}
```

The problem is: 
the switch() fires before the end of the isAuthorized() function. Thus, the switch() fires the default case (instead of isAuthorized('unknown user') == true). The function doesn't seem to wait for the database to be read...

How it is possible to make the switch() wait for the very end of the function isAuthorized()?

I've heard about callback-think, async, but I'm not able to sort all this thing in a clear order.. Any simple idea/help?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

The way your code is currently structured, this is not possible. 
See [`async` & `await`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await)

## Long answer

As you've already stated, you'd need to use callbacks. In your example, you'd have to check if the user is authorized first and then run the switch statement.

Pseudo Code:

```
function isAuthorized(user, callback) {

    // Run your mongoDB logic
    mongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO, function (err, db) {
        Users.find({ _id: From }).toArray(function (err, result) {
            var authorized = ...check if user is authorized...
            db.close();
            callback(authorized);
        });
    });
}
```

and then use it like that:

```
isAuthorized(yourUser, function (authorized) {
    if (authorized) {
        // business logic
    }
});
```

I hope this clears out some things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I went another direction using `promise`. The functions I need to run before running my switch are `promise(resolve,  reject)` and my switch is inside a `promise.all(...).then(..`       It did the trick. But I don't know if it's a valid way of working...